# How to convert the body of a clause into a list?

Tags: prolog

I've got a Prolog clause that looks like this:

```
inorder :- true(cell(1, 1, 1)), true(cell(1, 2, 2)), true(cell(1, 3, 3)),
           true(cell(2, 1, 4)), true(cell(2, 2, 5)), true(cell(2, 3, 6)),
           true(cell(3, 1, 7)), true(cell(3, 2, 8)), true(cell(3, 3, b)).
```

That I would like to convert into a list (say L) like this:

```
L = [cell(1, 1, 1), cell(1, 2, 2), cell(1, 3, 3),
     cell(2, 1, 4), cell(2, 2, 5), cell(2, 3, 6),
     cell(3, 1, 7), cell(3, 2, 8), cell(3, 3, b)].
```

The obvious way to start seems to be:

```
clause(inorder, Body).
```

But that produces:

```
Body = (true(cell(1, 1, 1)), true(cell(1, 2, 2)), true(cell(1, 3, 3)), true(cell(2, 1, 4)), true(cell(2, 2, 5)), true(cell(2, 3, 6)), true(cell(3, 1, 7)), true(cell(..., ..., ...)), true(cell(..., ..., ...))).
```

Which I'm not really sure how to extract the "trues" from? Any suggestions from the Prolog experts out there?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would have a construct such as the one you have for `inorder`, or why you would reuse the reserved Prolog word `true` as a functor, but you can break it down like this:

```
clause_body_list(Clause, Body) :-
    clause(Clause, Elements),
    clause_body_list_aux(Elements, Body).

clause_body_list_aux(Elements, [BodyPart|BodyRest]) :-
    Elements =.. [_, E | T],
    (   T = []
    ->  BodyPart = E,
        BodyRest = []
    ;   [ClauseRest] = T,
        true(BodyPart) = E,
        clause_body_list_aux(ClauseRest, BodyRest)
    ).
```

I suspect, in the bigger context, there may be a more sensible way of achieving what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks lurker, that works. The reason for the ungainly code is to write a Prolog player for general game playing as described at http://www.ggp.org/ (a really fun topic I discovered via an online course offered by Stanford logic professor Michael Genesereth). The example I'm using is from a GGP eight-puzzle. I don't have any say over how rules are written in GGP (which luckily is a dialect of Prolog), and it uses true(Base) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten lurker's answer to a more general solution, and also to my probably more novice level of Prolog.

```
clause_body_list(Clause, List) :-
    clause(Clause, Body),
    clause_body_list_aux(Body, List).

clause_body_list_aux(Element, [Element]) :-
    Element =.. [_Term1, _Term2].

clause_body_list_aux(Elements, [Term|Terms]) :-
    Elements =.. [_, Term|[Elements1]],
    clause_body_list_aux(Elements1, Terms).
```

The trick is to get rid of the leading ',' that '=..' places in front of the resulting list.

Then extracting a list of Bases from true(Base) could be done like

```
clause_body_list(inorder, List), findall(B, member(true(B), List), Bs), write(Bs).
```